# list view on click

Tags: android

how i can get the long kick on the row of listview

Answer (score 1):

listView.setOnItemLongClickListener

[check this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemLongClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener%29) for documentation of this method.

Comment: if i kick to show contextmenu1 and i long kick to show contextmenu2

Comment: Can you explain what you meant..Also do you mean 'click' when you say kick?

Answer (score 1):

For displaying ContextMenu on Long Press on Listview item , just go through this example:

[Show a context menu for long-clicks in an Android ListView](http://www.mikeplate.com/2010/01/21/show-a-context-menu-for-long-clicks-in-an-android-listview/)